# Как правильно сделать подсчет просмотров страницы? RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как правильно считать количество просмотров страниц? Сейчас просто в модели `Post` есть поле `views` и в контроллере делаем `@post.views += 1`. Как сделать грамотнее, чтобы просмотры страниц учитывались один раз от пользователя? Хранить в базе `IP` юзеров кто заходил или например ставить куки?

И еще в дополнение вопрос: такая статистика просмотров есть не только у этой модели, наверное будет правильнее вынести стату просмотров в отдельную модель?

Comment: Уникальность пользователя можно гарантировать лишь авторизацией оного (и даже это не защитит от второго/третьего аккаунта), в остальных случаях - будут погрешности по-любому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно хранить в отдельной таблице(создать отдельную модель) идентификатор сессии, имя просмотренной сущности, идентификатор просмотренной сущности. 
Перед экшеном `show` - проверять есть ли запись о просмотре в БД, если нет, то записывать.

P.S. Возможно есть гем с подобным функционалом.

Comment: да, нашел гем, который как раз это и делает https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist